# Read matrix from text file in C

Tags: c, matrix, text-files, fopen

I'm trying to read in a text file that's a 10x5 matrix of student ID#s and grades. I have a Chromebook. I've downloaded the file (grades.txt) and it's in downloads. I didn't save it anywhere else. I don't know how to `fopen` and read it. I eventually have to create another column for the average student score, etc. So far, I've got this:

```
int main();

FILE* spTemp

spTemp = fopen("??", "r");
```

How can I read the text file?

Answer (score 1):

Well the syntax for fopen is `somepointer = fopen("path to file(for example: \\\\C:\\myfile.txt)",[r,w,a,b,t])`

I think you can use a normal `/` instead of `\\`, too.

Edit: Since you are on a Chromebook, I think the path sould be: /home/[your username or chronos]/user/Downloads

Answer (score 0):

Initialise a File pointer (as you have done) for example: `FILE *fp` as you created the poiner you can assign to it the start adresss of your file. The function `fopen()`is good for that.

**Example**:

FILE *fp = fopen("path","access modifier");

-> Path can be an absolute path to your file, or even the filename if it is in the same directory

-> Access modifier can be `r`, if you want to read from the File, `w`to write. There exist lots of access modifier [r,w,a,b,t,w+] etc.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if your input file format is 5 numbers wide delimited by spaces (I'm assuming 10x5 means height x width). If not, swap rows and columns. Note that `grades.txt` (my example contents are shown below) should be in the same folder as the executable.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int m_rows = 10;
    int m_cols = 5;
    int m[m_rows][m_cols];
    FILE *fp = fopen("grades.txt", "r");
    int ret = 0;

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "unable to open grades.txt");
        return 1;
    }

    // read matrix from file
    for (int i = 0; i < m_rows && ret != EOF; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m_cols && ret != EOF; j++) {
            ret = fscanf(fp, "%d", &m[i][j]);

            if (ret == 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "fscanf format error reading grades.txt");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    // print the matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < m_rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m_cols; j++) {
            printf("%d ", m[i][j]);
        }

        puts("");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output (identical to source text input):

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35
36 37 38 39 40
41 42 43 44 45
46 47 48 49 50
```

Comment: People on SO shouldn't code the whole program for OP`s question.

Comment: It's hit or miss. The crux of the matter is if the question is designated "Homework". Then suggestions that lead the OP to the solution are better advised. For a demonstration of `fopen`, etc.. a short example is more informative. Though here, the failure to *validate* the file is open for reading and failure to *validate* the return of `fscanf` detracts from its usefulness (and greatly increases the chance of invoking *Undefined Behavior*)